# Solving an equation for b/a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the following for b/a and I'm stuck at the third step.

**Equation:**

$\frac{a\,-\,b}{d}=\frac{a\,-\,c\,\cdot\,(a\,-\,b)}{d\,+\,e\,+\,f}$

**Step 1:**

$\frac{(a\,-\,b)\,\cdot\,(d\,+\,e\,+\,f)}{d\,\cdot\,[\,a\,-\,c\,\cdot\,(a\,-\,b)\,]}=1$

**Step 2:**

$\frac{a\,-\,b}{a\,-\,c\,\cdot\,(a\,-\,b)}=\frac{d}{d\,+\,e\,+\,f}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Try to factor by $a$ both at the numerator and the denominator on the left hand side.

Comment: Please don’t use tags you don’t understand. General rule of thumb: Get rid of denominators entirely at step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from your Step two, you have written the following:

$\frac{a\,-\,b}{a\,-\,c\,\cdot\,(a\,-\,b)}=\frac{d}{d\,+\,e\,+\,f}$

I will denote the RHS by L to simplify the writing, that is

$L=\frac{d}{d+e+f}$

Then your step two can be rewritten as $\frac{a-b}{a-c \cdot (a-b)}=L$

We proceed by factoring out 'a' from the numerator and denominator (after expanding it out) of the LHS, just as KBS suggested in the comments section, you should get the following:

$\frac{a(1-\frac{b}{a})}{a(1-c+c\frac{b}{a})}=\frac{1-\frac{b}{a}}{1-c+c\frac{b}{a}}$

So then our earlier equation becomes

$\frac{1-\frac{b}{a}}{1-c+c\frac{b}{a}}=L$

or equivalently

$1-\frac{b}{a}=(1-c)L+cL\frac{b}{a}$

Solving for $\frac{b}{a}$ you should get something along the lines of

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{1-(1-c)L}{cL+1}$

Substituting back in L we get the following equivalent representations for $\frac{b}{a}$

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{1-(1-c)\frac{d}{d+e+f}}{c\frac{d}{d+e+f}+1}=\frac{d+e+f}{cd+d+e+f}-\frac{(1-c)d}{cd+d+e+f}$